# Scrappy: Extracting data from sub pages

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to extract price details from such web [links](https://www.alinea.com/fr-fr/p/vence-canape-1.5-places-fixe-en-lin-vert-cedre-26943589.html) using ***scrapy***. When I select each color browser sends a new ajax request to the server. eg for color [Vert cèdre](https://www.alinea.com/on/demandware.store/Sites-ALI_FR-Site/fr/Product-Variation?pid=90001557&dwvar_90001557_color=Gris%20borie&Quantity=1&format=ajax&productlistid=undefined).

```
import scrapy

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Test"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.alinea.com/fr-fr/p/vence-canape-1.5-places-fixe-en-lin-vert-cedre-26943589.html',
            '... other URL's',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        # extract each color and color url
        # hit each color page url to get pricing details
```

Scrappy gives me contents of the [main page](https://www.alinea.com/fr-fr/p/vence-canape-1.5-places-fixe-en-lin-vert-cedre-26943589.html) in the parse function. My question is how I can hit the sub page links (for colors) and extract the contents from it in the parse method so I can get the pricing detail for each color in a single object.

eg

```
{
  'url': 'https://www.alinea.com/fr-fr/p/vence-canape-1.5-places-fixe-en-lin-vert-cedre-26943589.html'
  'pricing': [{
      'color': 'Beige roucas',
      'price': '699,00 €'
   },{
      'color': 'Blanc capelan',
      'price': '699,00 €'
   }
   ....... other colors
  ]
}
```

If I yield color page url's from parse method as new requests, how can I merge pricing to get above structure.

Answer (score 1):

After going over some links, doesn't seem like the prices changes with color (if I'm wrong then, you'd probably use [CrawlSpider with rules](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=rule#scrapy.spiders.Rule) or [Splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) together with Scrapy for a more robust spider).
But for now, for the color, their respective links etc., you could try the `parse` function below. Edit accordingly.

```py
    def parse(self, response):
        url = response.url
        
        price = response.xpath('//*[@class="product-price product-pricing"]/div/span/text()').get().strip()
        
        prices = []
        
        # Selector for the color options
        color_list = response.xpath('//*/li[@class="attribute attr-color "]/div[@class="value full-line"]/select/option')
        
        # Check if that selector exists &
        # Cycle through colors adding the data
        if color_list:
            for color_data in color_list:
                prices.append({
                    'color': color_data.xpath('@data-title').get().rsplit(':: ')[1],
                    'price': price,
                    'link': color_data.xpath('@data-link').get()
                })
        
        yield {
            'url': url,
            'pricing': prices,
        }
```

Comment: Here is another(rather correct) example. https://www.surlatable.com/staub-enameled-cast-iron-grill-pans-1234/PRO-5113089.html?cgid=SCA-389628